# HTML/JS: Calling a value from an object constructed onload in <body>

Tags: javascript, html, oop, onload

I'm currently making a website, and I'm creating a "manager" object onload in the body:

```
body id="real-world" onload="createARSim('ar-world','real-world','phone');">
```

createARSim(...) returns an object with a bunch of things in it that are useful.  One such thing is a

```
var pageIndex
```

which monitors the current page.

I want to display the page number somewhere in the web page.  Currently I am putting the code inline, like this:

```
<script> onload.pageIndex.toString(); </script>
```

the issue is that it throws this error:

```
TypeError: onload.pageIndex is undefined
```

And I'm not sure what to do about it.  The js code in the constructor runs fine, but I can't find any way to access the returned object once I've finished running the constructor.

EDIT:

ok, I think I might know why it's not working.  First, I need to use Document.onload to call the onload object that I've returned.  However the bigger issue is how onload works -- I can't call an element of onload inline, because the constructor isn't actually executed yet when I run the inline javascript code (it calls after everything has loaded...).

So I can't just put it inline.  I'll have to do some clever editing from the javascript to the div I'm putting it in directly, I think.

Comment: I don't know if this code is supposed to work but.. Anyway, aren't you supposed to call document.onload.pageIndex instead? onload itself shouldn't be an object.

Comment: Good point.  That solves one problem (my lack of knowledge of how onload actually works), but now it's saying that document.onload is null.  Is this because it runs the inline script before the document actually loads (runs the constructor when body finishes loading)?

Comment: Actually, either document.onload, window.onload and body.onload should be firing AFTER the whole document has been loaded. However, instead of doing it in this way, I would rather use the function createARSim after the document has been loaded. remove it from onload and try this on the script: `window.onload = function(){ this.pageIndex = createARSim('ar-world','real-world','phone'); };` then: `alert(window.pageIndex);`.. However I'm more familiar using jQuery, so please try the above script and tell me if something happens :). EDIT: actually document.onload fires when the HTML has been parsed

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to solve this problem

```
window.onload = function() {
 var pageIndex = createARSim('ar-world','real-world','phone').pageIndex;
 var textNode = document.createElement('text');
 textNode.textContent = pageIndex;
 document.body.appendChild(textNode);
}
```

This appends pageIndex to body.